# Deleting triples identified by subject and predicate only

Tags: sparql, rdf

I can delete a triple identifying it by each of the three elements:

```
DELETE DATA 
{ GRAPH <http://my.graph.com>
   {
      <http://my.domain.com/foo> <http://standard.com/catalog#title> "ABC" .
   }
};
```

If I omit `"ABC"`I get an error.  How can I delete triples identifying them by only the first two elements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want **delete where**:

```
delete where { <http://some-subject> <http://some-predicate> ?anyObject }
```